# Error WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError in testing with stub using minitest in rails (using Faraday)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, faraday, webmock

I'm trying to create a test to check the correct behaviout of my service object,

```rb
def api_call_post(connection, message, url)
    pp message
    response = connection.post do |conn|
      conn.url url
      conn.body = message
      conn.headers = @headers
    end
    check_response(response)
  end
...
```

this is the test :

```rb
test "create a title" do

   body = { "name" => 'some name',
                "external_id" =>'004',
                "title_type" =>'feature',
                "tags" => 'some tag' }.to_json

    puts body

    stub_request(:post, "some web")
      .with(body: body )
      .to_return(status: 201, body: "Created", headers: {})

    response = MovidaApi.new(payload).create_title

    assert response.success?
    assert_equal "Created", response.body
  end
...
```

The problem comes when I include the `.with` in the stub, (without it's working ok),
I printed statements and the output are exactly the same.

The error is:

Error:
MovidaApiTest#test_create_a_title:
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST some web with headers
{'Accept'=>'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Length'=>'0', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

What i'm doing wrong?

I tried to use the snippet suggested but still don't work.

I expect the test to pass

Comment: Call this before the stub   `WebMock.allow_net_connect!`

Comment: They only way to do is doing real calls? I want to avoid do real calls to the endpoints.

Comment: No, just try adding the call.

Comment: I tried and seemed to hit the real endpoint, that is a problem because the call is to create a new register in a DB, and I don't wan to create a register in every test... (maybe I'm wrong...)